# Are there any free tools that will allow me to view my RoR sqlite3 DBs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Are there any free GUI tools that will allow me to view the contents of my RoR sqlite3 DBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extremely recommend to use the [sqlite3 firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/), since it works on macs and pcs.

It works pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of tools that can be used to view sqlite3 databases graphically, I've used this one: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/